# Bot responding multiple times to a message based on the amount of trigger words discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I want the bot to only respond to one trigger at a time.

For example, if I ping the bot and also put in a trigger word, it will respond twice. Same goes for if I send multiple trigger words it will also respond back with however many trigger words there were. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or how to make it stop once it sees one trigger word or when it gets pinged.

```
banned = ['x', 'y', 'z']
insults = ['x', 'y', 'z']
mentions = ["x", "y", "z"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('x'))
  print('Bot is ready')
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
      if message.mention_everyone:
        return
      else:
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(mentions))
    for word in banned:
      if word in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(insults))
```

Comment: Use `break` to break out of the loop when you find a banned word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break out of the loop after sending the insult. Or you can use the `any()` function.

To prevent responding to both the ping and trigger words, return from the function after responding to the ping.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        if not message.mention_everyone:
            await message.channel.send(random.choice(mentions))
        return
    if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in banned):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(insults))
```

Comment: That solves the issue with it responding to multiple trigger words, but how do I stop it from responding to both a ping and a trigger word? It's giving me an error when I input a break anywhere

Comment: You can return from the function after responding to a ping.

Comment: That or using `elif` instead of multiple `if`

Comment: @Benjin Yes, although some believe that else-less programming is a feature, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EumXak7TyQ0.  I'm not a total convert, but since the code in the OP was written in this style, I maintained it to solve the problem.